# Print user input using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print the user input of a package name. I have the following code.

```
packageList = []
package = input("Enter name: ")
while package == '' :
    print("Package name cannot be blank")
    packagename = input("Enter name: ")
    packageList.append(packageName)

print ((packageName) + "added")
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. An error is being displayed: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'packageName' referenced before assignment

Comment: You never made a `packageName` variable. Perhaps you meant for `package` and `packageName` to be the same variable, and mixed up which name you were using.

Comment: Also, `packageList.append(packageName)` should definitely not be in that loop.

Comment: Thank you!!! That was so simple. I've been trying for ages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is giving you errors because you're mixing up the use of variables `package` and `packageName`, when it looks like you should be using the same variable in both places. 
The code in aj8uppal's answer corrects most of this (by replacing most references to both variables with `packagename`), but he never clearly describes that this is the problem (and he still leaves one reference to `package` in the `while` condition).

Here's some actually fixed code:

```
packageList = []
package = input("Enter name: ")

while package == '' :
    print("Package name cannot be blank")
    package = input("Enter name: ")               # assign to package variable here

packageList.append(package)                       # unindent, and use package again

print ((package) + "added")                       # use package rather than packageName
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `packageList.append(packageName)` should not be in the `while` loop. Your `while` loop just makes sure the input is not blank, so we don't want to append it.

**What you are doing is not raising the error, so `packageName` doesn't exist.** Therefore, you are printing an uncalled variable.

Also, you call `package = input(...)`, but if there is an error, you call `packagename = input(...)`. You probably want to change that.

**Here is your edited code:**

```
packageList = []
packagename = input("Enter name: ")
while package name == '' :
    print("Package name cannot be blank")
    packagename = input("Enter name: ")

packageList.append(packageName)
print ((packageName) + "added")
```